# Babel Transform React.Web allow decorator plugin

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, babeljs

I am using React (for ASP.NET web forms https://reactjs.net/guides/weboptimizer.html) to transpile my JSX files. I am trying to use Mobx as my store for React. Unfortunately I am getting this error:

> React.Exceptions.BabelException: Error: unknown: Decorators are not supported yet in 6.x pending proposal update.

After spending some time googling around I see that I have to add a Babel plug-in for decorators. Unfortunately I am not sure how to do it with this approach. The moment it tries to compile my jsx files it breaks. My .babelrc file is ignored at this point as it is all done server side and not client side. Can someone please assist me on this?

Comment: I still have not figure out the issue yet. So I am now using Mobx without decorators. I managed to make it work without decorators. I am not happy with it but I have not been able to find a solution yet. How did you add the plugin? In the .babelrc? Or in the c# code behind?